# Why would NavigationrLink fire when 'isActive' is false?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

**Note:** This is a simplified version of my original problem.

**Problem:** Why when I tap anywhere within my view, I activate the NavigationLink when the '**isActive**' parameter is set to 

false?

Expectation:

 *** No Action ***

*I believe this is a bug.*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDataResultViewActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView(), isActive: $isDataResultViewActive) {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not in the NavigationLink, would you provide your code that depicts the problem?

Comment: I've replace my origin code (above) with a very simple test code to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: What do you meant by *anywhere within my view*. Here it is activated only when I tap into "Hello, world!", as expected. Xcode 12 / iOS 14. Which environment do you use?

Comment: Xcode 12/iOS 14.   Still, the link should remain DEACTIVATED per parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I had applied the NavigationLink template **INCORRECTLY**.

**Solution:**
*I should wrap the NavigationLink around a button that toggles it*; NOT the entire container view (which doing so, causes trigger when user taps ANYWHERE with the container view, which I don't want).  ☝️

Comment: In my case I had NavigationView { ZStack { ScrollView { VStack .... and when I put NavigationLink in the middle(bottom) it worked! try to put it all the way in the stacks